# Show/hide sibling div based on content

Tags: css, conditional-statements, logic

Hello – I would like to show content in a div based on the content in another div. For example, if sibling1 is empty, I would like to hide sibling2 (in parent1 below). If sibling1 has content, I would like to show sibling2 (parent2 below). I'd prefer to be able to do this with CSS, is this possible? If not, I can work with a simple javascript suggestion as well.

```
<!---hide sibling2--->
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="sibling1"></div>
    <div class="sibling2">hide</div>
</div>

<!---show sibling2--->
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="sibling1">has content</div>
    <div class="sibling2">show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I have tried multiple routes, hence why I'm asking here. I've provided a simplified code to keep my question straight to the point without muddying it with my awkward attempts. I've tried :empty & :has selectors, as well as ~ & + to group siblings via CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D this is actually very simple with CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
.sibling1 { background: green; }
.sibling2 { background: red; }
.sibling1:empty + .sibling2 { display: none; }
```

```html
<!---hide sibling2--->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling1"></div>
    <div class="sibling2">hide</div>
</div>

<!---show sibling2--->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling1">has content</div>
    <div class="sibling2">show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had some version of this at one point, but my syntax was slightly off. Much appreciated.

Comment: if you want all siblings, not just the immediate one, swap `+` for `~`. glad i could help :)